# Over Hook Accent in pdfLatex

Tags: pdftex, unicode-math, accents

the over hook accent is available in `unicode-math` that is accessible via `xelatex`.
I have a relatively large `pdflatex` project and need to add 2 or 3 over hook accent.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows it in xelatex?  Can you give us a pointer to know what it looks like?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: What letters with the hook do you need? Are they for writing some Vietnamese name?

Comment: yes this is a vietnamese world. I have the 'o' horn enable with `\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}` and `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ohorn}{T5}`. I like to add to it an over hook accent.

Answer (score 1):

found it, simply use `\h`command from

```
\usepackage{vntex}
```

for example, for a hook above a o horn,
`\h{\ohorn}` gives [image].

no need of `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ohorn}{T5}` for the o horn as mentioned in my previous comment. T5 font comes with `vntex`.

Comment: You might want to consider a picture of the the output - that way it's a little easier for people to see what the code yields....